# URL for Forge BIM 360 parameter values

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a Forge URL to get the values for each of the parameters listed at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/parameters/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can query these parameters for your projects. See docs here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/#body-structure-200.

Or for a specific project: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-GET/

Comment: To clarify, we have an application that creates BIM 360 projects and the user needs to select the appropriate parameter values from UI controls. We want to populate the controls with the parameter values deserialized from a JSON array returned from a URL and not hard code them.

Comment: Unfortunately we don’t exactly have a public endpoint for that purpose but a hacky way to go would be to query a project and take the keys of the response object and turn them into more readable form labels with library such as this [one](https://github.com/brutusin/json-forms/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no url for those parameters at a moment. For example, I'm aware there is a wish to obtain country and  state_or_province, which currently hard coded:

HQ-2520
"External API request: obtain 'country' and 'state_or_province' list automatically"

Let us know if you have specific parameters in mind. We will log a wish.